# Cant get my purchased app on my iPad

Tags: iphone, ios

I purchased a game on my iPhone and can download it to my iPad. But it says that I still need to purchase it to not to play in the "free mode". I have already paid on my iPhone. The iPad and the iPhone, both are associated with the same account.

Comment: Sounds like the purchase you made was an in-game purchase...  and that company likely doesn't transfer those between devices.    So the app is free...  but any purchases you make in the app to unlock it are device specific.

Comment: The app would have to have a "restore purchases" function that you need to perform.